# Bind mounted /var to /raid5/var and CentOS fails to boot

Tags: centos, bind-mount, var

**System Background:** I am running CentOS 7 in a VM (in VirtualBox) on a host computer running Windows 10. My /dev/sda is on an SSD and then I have three 1TB HDDs /dev/sdb, /dev/sdc, and /dev/sdd configured into a RAID 5 drive called /dev/md5. The /dev/md5 is formatted as ext4 and is mounted to /raid5.

I wanted to bind mount both /home and /var to sub-directories in my RAID 5, /dev/md5.

The following steps worked just fine for /home:

```
mkdir /raid5/home
rsync -av /home/*/raid5 /home
mount --bind /raid5/home /home

nano /etc/fstab
...
/raid5/home /home none bind 0 0
```

I then restart CentOS and it boots no problem. I check `df -aTh` and both /raid5/home and /home show mounted to /dev/md5.

I follow the exact same process to bind mount /var and /raid5/var and upon reboot I can't even get to the login screen. Same exact commands were used, just substitute /var everywhere you see /home.

FYI, I just started using CentOS/Linux last weekend so I only have 1 week of experience so far. I'm familiar with a lot of the Terminal commands, partitioning, formatting, and mounting drives, installing software, etc. I'm not as familiar with the file/directory permissions (I have a gut feeling when I bind /var to /raid5/var some important software is no longer able to access directories it needs).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you used same step for `/var` in `fstab` as for `/home`. The issue might be caused by incorrect SELinux file contexts (since `rsync -a` does not copy xattrs).

You should be able to boot SELinux in *permissive* mode by [temporarily changing kernel boot options](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter) to include `enforcing=0`.

If you now can boot, the issue is in incorrect SELinux labels. To fix them, run `restorecon -R /var`. The system should boot normally at next reboot.

You should also add a file labeling rule to disable automatic relabeling from being applied to `/raid5`:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t "<<none>>" "/raid5(/.*)?"
```

Answer (score -1):

It has been a while, but this is ringing a bell... are any of these logical volumes? I think you may want to read through this answer...

[CentOS moving var](https://serverfault.com/questions/695350/centos-moving-var-to-a-new-disk-partition)

As per those instructions:
Boot the rescue media. Escape to shell.

Scan for volume groups: lvm vgscan -v

Activate all volume groups: lvm vgchange -a y

List logical volumes: lvm lvs –all

With this information, and the volumes activated, you should be able to mount the volumes: mount /dev/volumegroup/logicalvolume /mountpoint

Comment: Possibly not LVM volumes, since looks like mdraid is being used.

Comment: /dev/sda is a logical volume; while /dev/sdb, /dev/sdc, /dev/sdd are all fixed at 931 GB so that I can run them in RAID 5.